# why indexing ndarray of picture like this makes picture green and blue?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-image

```
   import numpy as np
    from skimage import io 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    jeju = io.imread('jeju.jpg')

    jeju.shape 

> (960,1280,3)

    jeju

> Array([[[171, 222, 251],
        [172, 223, 252],
        [172, 223, 252],
        ...,
        [124, 189, 255],
        [121, 189, 254],
        [120, 188, 253]],

       [[173, 224, 253],
        [173, 224, 253],
        [173, 224, 253],
        ...,
        [124, 189, 255],
        [122, 190, 255],
        [121, 189, 254]],

       [[174, 225, 254],
        [174, 225, 254],
        [175, 226, 255]
        ...,
        [125, 190, 255],
        [122, 190, 255],
        [122, 190, 255]],

       ...,

       [[ 66,  93,  26],
        [ 89, 114,  46],
        [ 49,  72,   2],
        ...,
        [  2,  29,   0],
        [ 34,  59,  17],
        [ 40,  63,  21]],

       [[ 44,  71,   4],
        [ 23,  50,   0],
        [ 29,  52,   0],
        ...,
        [ 40,  67,  22],
        [  0,  19,   0],
        [ 16,  41,   0]],

       [[ 29,  58,   0],
        [ 44,  71,   2],
        [ 84, 110,  37],
        ...,
        [ 17,  44,   1],
        [ 33,  60,  17],
        [ 18,  43,   1]]], dtype=uint8)
    
    plt.imshow(jeju)


    
    plt.imshow(jeju[:,:,0])



    jeju[:,:,0]

>Array([[171, 172, 172, ..., 124, 121, 120],
       [173, 173, 173, ..., 124, 122, 121],
       [174, 174, 175, ..., 125, 122, 122],
       ...,
       [ 66,  89,  49, ...,   2,  34,  40],
       [ 44,  23,  29, ...,  40,   0,  16],
       [ 29,  44,  84, ...,  17,  33,  18]], dtype=uint8)

    ---------------------------------------------
```

As above, I read picture from directory and index it to make picture red.
Because (960, 1280, 3) from `jeju.shape` is (height,width,rgb) and I thought that if I used `[:,:,0]`, 0 meant red.( I thought r=0,g=1,b=2)
But result was not red picture but picture full of green and blue.
Why this thing happened? What `[:,:,0]` means in real?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Green and blue are from the default colormap, 'viridis'. You could provide a different colormap, Best also add `vmin=0` and `vmax=255` to prevent that the colors get smeared out to the complete range: `plt.imshow(..., cmap='Reds', vmin=0, vmax=255)`.

Comment: Thanks. result was what I wanted. But I am not still convinced of what [:,:,0] actually do. [:,:,1] and [:,:,2] also make similar results (picture with green and blue) and I don't understand how 0,1,2 are related to rgb color.

Comment: `[:,:,0]` produces a 2d array.  It's not 'labeled' as the red component.  It might as well be a b/w array.  If you want to show red, you need the full `rgb`, but with `jeju[:,:,1:] = 0`, the other colors set to 0.

Comment: Ah,I think I get the point. Then 2d array means brightness of pixels and it should be grayscale picture but because of colormap,it becomes picture with green and blue.Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that it represents the red channel. However, the function imshow, from the official documentation stated that for a 2d array, *The values are mapped to colors using normalization and a colormap.*

If you want to plot your red channel only you can do this

```
red_image = np.zeros(np.shape(jeju))
red_image[:, :, 0] = jeju[:, :, 0]

plt.imshow(red_image.astype('uint8'))
```

Comment: I did as you told me. But it was just full red picture.

Comment: I edited the code. Is that what you were looking for ?